# Spring security and Stomp not seeing headers

Tags: spring-security, stomp

I have a spring security application and I'm trying implement websockets using Stomp.

The application is mainly REST based, using tokens for security. All requests coming in have to a security token in the header.

The problem is when setting up a simple Stomp client using basic html, spring appears to not be seeing any headers.

The client works fine if I disable the security, in which case no headers are passed in.

```
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/project/ws/wsendpoint');
var headers = {'Auth': 'some_auth_token'}
writeConsole("Created socket");
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect(headers, function(frame) {
    writeConsole("Connected to via WebSocket");
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/push', function(message) 
        { writeConsole(message.body);}, headers );
    });
window.onbeforeunload = disconnectClient;
```

Heres the relevant spring configuration

```
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) 
            .and()
            .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated() authenticated.
            .and()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()); 

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

The doFilter in the authenticationTokenFilter class should see the header field 'Auth', as set in the client, however nothing is there.

Comment: Using wireshark, it appears that the header field isn't being sent, suggesting the problem is in the client code. I've looked at the Stomp documentation, the code, and examples, I can't see any issue with what I've done.

Comment: When you add headers on the SockJs client, it adds them as attributes under the header "native headers". IE: 'nativeHeaders={token=[testtoken], accept-version=[1.1,1.0], heart-beat=[10000,10000]}'. Note that 'token' is my custom header I am adding on the client side.

Comment: Would you be OK to pass it in as a query parameter instead of a header?  That can be done.  Or if you solved this I would love to know what you ended up doing.

Comment: Hi, that's what we ended up doing in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending header, you can replace sessionId with your own ID.

```
var sessionId = utils.random_string(36);
var socket = new SockJS('/socket', [], {
    sessionId: () => {
       return sessionId
    }
 });

stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect(headers, function(frame) {
    writeConsole("Connected to via WebSocket");
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/push', function(message) 
        { writeConsole(message.body);}, headers );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Stomp cannot send any custom headers during the initial authentication stage. The way round this was to send the authentication token as a query parameter (would not recommended for non-closed systems).